# show jquery array number in html link href

Tags: jquery, html

I show my id in jquery with this

```
// jquery code
active = $('#rate_slider li.active').attr('id');
//jquery code
```

no i send this active in href link :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="content" onclick="getdata('data.php?id=active','send');">submit</a>
```

Note : id = active / is generate jquery id

Thanks For Any Help.

Comment: To clarify; you're asking why the `active` variable is not getting replaced when you call `getdata()`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
"getdata('data.php?id='+active,'send');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question title, I think this may be what you want

```
<a id="yourLink" class="content">submit</a>
```

And then:

```
active = $('#rate_slider li.active').attr('id');
$("#yourLink").attr("href", "data.php?id=" + active);
```

Or if you don't want this active value in your href, but actually do want to call `getData` when the link is clicked, then this should work

```
<a id="yourLink" href="javascript:void(0);" class="content">submit</a>

active = $('#rate_slider li.active').attr('id');
$("#yourLink").click(function() { 
   getdata('data.php?id=' + active,'send');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating active like a string in your example and you need to treat it like a variable. I'm not even positive that will work because it is typical to wrap jQuery in an anonymous function. So your inline `onclick` statement is likely to fail. I would do it like this instead. If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should be using `prop` instead of `attr`.

```
<!-- dont set href to void. just set it to a hash instead. dont set onclick inline -->
<a href="#" class="content">submit</a>
```

```
//you may need to add var to active. you didnt post enough code so cant know for sure
var active = $('#rate_slider li.active').prop('id');

//use jquerys click handlers instead of inline onclick statements
$('#yourLink').click( function() {
   getdata('data.php?id' + active,'send');
   return false; //prevent link navigation
});
```

Now that I think about it I believe you are trying to get the currently active list item when submit is clicked. In which case you would want to make that call inside your click event.

```
$('#yourLink').click( function() {
   var active = $('#rate_slider li.active').prop('id');
   getdata('data.php?id' + active,'send');
   return false; //prevent link navigation
});
```